# Vídeo continua executando ao fechar modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um modal do bootstrap que abre automaticamente quando a página é carregada. Dentro desse modal há apenas um vídeo. Porém, quando esse vídeo é executado e o modal é fechado o vídeo continua em execução. Como faço para, ao fechar o modal parar de executar o vídeo (iframe do youtube).

```
<div class="modal fade" id="testemodal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">xxx</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NHqZKNfAVa0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> -->
            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> -->
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function closeModal() {
//código para dar stop no vídeo aqui
//use $('#youriframeid').remove(); para forçar a remoção do html do iFrame
//caso queira alguma alternativa para parar o vídeo
$('#youriframeid').remove();

//código para fechar a modal aqui
$("#testemodal").modal("hide");
}
```

Agora apenas execute essa função quando precisar fechar a modal. Espero ter contribuído.

Comment: Ae funcionou, vlw fera ;)

Answer (score 1):

Dessa maneira:

`$('#youriframeid').attr('src',$('#youriframeid').attr('src'));`

Se você fizer um ".remove()" e depois abrir o modal novamente, o seu vídeo não estará mais lá. Dependendo da sua necessidade também atende, mas não parece ser o mais indicado, a não ser que você crie o modal todas as vezes que o abre.

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem vários modais de vídeo, a melhor maneira de lidar com isso é esta:

```
$('#testemodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var $iframes = $(e.target).find('iframe');
        $iframes.each(function(index, iframe) {
            $(iframe).attr("src", $(iframe).attr('src'));
        });
    });
```

Isto passa por todos os iframes em seus modais e redefine-los, em vez de substituir o src de todos os seus iframe para o primeiro vídeo no seu conjunto modal.